# Error Airflow in Dockerfile is not creating the database

Tags: python, docker, sqlalchemy, airflow

I am getting the error below when I am running the Airflow with docker-compose in a Macos environment.

```
> webserver_1  | [2021-04-23 07:30:27,971] {abstract.py:229} ERROR -
> Failed to add operation for GET /api/v1/connections webserver_1  |
> Traceback (most recent call last): webserver_1  |   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/connexion/apis/abstract.py",
> line 209, in add_paths webserver_1  |     self.add_operation(path,
> method) webserver_1  |   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/connexion/apis/abstract.py",
> line 173, in add_operation webserver_1  |    
> pass_context_arg_name=self.pass_context_arg_name webserver_1  |   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/connexion/operations/__init__.py",
> line 8, in make_operation webserver_1  |     return
> spec.operation_cls.from_spec(spec, *args, **kwargs) webserver_1  |  
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/connexion/operations/openapi.py",
> line 138, in from_spec webserver_1  |     **kwargs webserver_1  |  
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/connexion/operations/openapi.py",
> line 89, in __init__ webserver_1  |    
> pass_context_arg_name=pass_context_arg_name webserver_1  |   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/connexion/operations/abstract.py",
> line 96, in __init__ webserver_1  |     self._resolution =
> resolver.resolve(self) webserver_1  |   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/connexion/resolver.py", line
> 40, in resolve webserver_1  |     return
> Resolution(self.resolve_function_from_operation_id(operation_id),
> operation_id) webserver_1  |   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/connexion/resolver.py", line
> 66, in resolve_function_from_operation_id webserver_1  |     raise
> ResolverError(str(e), sys.exc_info()) webserver_1  |
> connexion.exceptions.ResolverError: <ResolverError: columns>
```

https://pastebin.com/hSpcthUS

It is not creating the database due to a problem with SqlAlchemy.

Comment: what was the solution to this issue? I'm facing the same error. Any tips will help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this [pull request](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/pull/618#issuecomment-810749906). You need to add SQLAlchemy==1.3.23\ to your docker file for this to work